# Балансировка (нужно оптимизировать код)

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Есть задача, нужно отбалансировать список чисел так, чтобы в итоге вывело минимальную абсолютную разницу.
Нужно ускорить , чтобы можно было быстро посчитать до 10^6 входных чисел.

```
Входные данные:
n = количество чисел
Количество чисел до n

Пример входа:
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
Выход:
0
Потому что 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 - 6
Минимальная абсолютная разница = 0
```

Мой код:

```
n = int(input())
list_of_nums = list(map(int,input().split()))
minim = 9999999999
for i in range(len(list_of_nums)):
    tmp = abs( sum(list_of_nums[i + 1:]) - sum(list_of_nums[:i+1]) )
    if tmp < minim:
        minim = tmp
print(minim)
```

Comment: делите список пополам и сдвигайтесь в сторону, где больше

Comment: минусы и плюсы могут быть в любом порядке или все минусы слева. а плюсы - справа. Для [1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2] какой должен быть результат?

Comment: Всё , спасибо большое, уже помогли, только я всё равно не понимаю, range(1, len(list_of_nums) - 1) быстрее , чем range(len(list_of_nums))

Comment: @Michaelan Ничем не быстрее

Comment: Почему в примере разница 0? Что насчёт вопроса Эникейщика? В связи с последним - какой будет ответ для n=8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если взять ваш код за основу, то

1. вместо `range(len(list_of_nums))` надо все таки проходить `range(1, len(list_of_nums) - 1)`
2. ваш код из-за вычисления сумм имеет сложность O(n^2), хотя можно уложиться в O(n):

например чтобы получать суммы не надо считать сумму всех элементов слева и справа от `i`, а достаточно увеличивать и уменьшать суммы на один элемент

кстати это позволяет избавиться от вашего узкого места с `minim = 9999999999`, ведь можно предложить список чисел, значительно больших `9999999999`

код:

```
left = sum(arr[:1])
right = sum(arr[1:])
minim = abs(left - right)

for i in range(1, len(arr) - 1):
    left += arr[i]
    right -= arr[i]
 
    tmp = abs(left - right)
    if tmp < minim:
        minim = tmp

print(minim)
```

по идее можно попробовать оптимизировать abs, перейдя к квадратам, но, честно говоря, я не знаю что быстрее, если `abs` делается через `if`, тогда работа с квадратами быстрее, если через сброс бита знака, то `abs` быстрее

Comment: Можете обьяснить почему вместо range(len(list_of_nums)) надо проходить range(1, len(list_of_nums) - 1) ? 
Сложность O(n^2), я сразу понял, что имею таккую сложность , но не знал как её уменьшить, у меня постоянно получается решить задачу, но из-за сложности она не проходит.

Comment: потому что все таки мне кажется слева сумма хотя бы какая-то должна быть, хотя бы 1 элемент, тоже самое и для суммы справа

Comment: Спасибо , как же всё логично.